# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem() method to start at a different position

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm making a very simple app using the ViewPager. I would like to be able to start at a custom position when the getItem method is called. Below is my current code.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {        
    case 0: 
        Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        return fragment1;
    case 1: 
        Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        return fragment2;
    case 2: 
        Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
        return fragment3;     

    default:
        return null;  
    }
```

I was wondering how it would be possible to start at position 1 instead of 0 when the getItem method is called and then to be able to swipe to position 0 or 2 from position 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply set selected item to 1 after setting adapter?

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```